# Regex - 3 data from [abcd] abcd efhg (abcd)

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have string:

```
[18d03] Complete screen 12" (tablet)
```

And I want to get:

```
$one = '18d03';
$two = 'Complete screen 12"';
$three = 'tablet';
```

Now I make this:

```
preg_match('/^(.+?)\s*\(([^)]+)\)$/', $local->parts_name, $explode);
```

But this regex don't see first `18d03`.

Comment: http://regexr.com/3fpvr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this but `/^\[(.+)\] (.+?) \((.+)\)$/` should do what you want. The `\`s esape characters that have special meanings.

You can preview it at http://regexr.com/3fq01

Comment: For better performance, the first dot matching pattern should be lazy (`\[(.+)\]` -> `\[(.+?)]`, or even `\[(\w+)]` if only word chars are expected).

Comment: That's interesting; I didn't realise there was a performance benefit from using lazy matching.

Comment: No, there is not direct correlation, it is context-dependent. Here, `]` is expected closer to the initial `[`, not to the end of the string, so lazy quantifier is more natural to use in this situation.